# In c# how to split json objects into smaller objects and store in a string array

Tags: c#, json

I have to send data in json format, but they have to be of small sizes. I get data(str) as follows

```
[{"CombinationCode":127,"Pattern":"4545,.86,4520,.44,4592"},{"CombinationCode":128,"Pattern":"4545,.86,4520,.44,4592"},{"CombinationCode":129,"Pattern":"4545,.86,4520,.44,4592"}]
```

If I want the max size to be 165, I want to chunk the data to pieces smaller than 165(maxLength), and a whole json tuple should be included. Like the above should be separated as 2 string arrays

```
 [{"CombinationCode":127,"Pattern":"4545,.86,4520,.44,4592"},{"CombinationCode":128,"Pattern":"4545,.86,4520,.44,4592"}]
```

and

```
[{"CombinationCode":129,"Pattern":"4545,.86,4520,.44,4592"}]
```

How will I do this. I tried the following code, but it separates it according to only size, and not tuples

```
for (int index = 0; index < str.Length; index += maxLength) {
    Console.WriteLine("DataPart {0}",str.Substring(index, Math.Min(maxLength, str.Length - index)));
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the chunked strings to be valid json, or you just trying to split it up and put it back together before de/serializing?

Comment: I want the chunked strings to be valid jsons

Comment: Im not sure why you think sending 165 bytes at a time will be more efficient than just sending the whole lot - unless the total package is huge your network overhead will easily outweigh any imprvement made

Comment: I  sending it through iothub and that allows to send only small packets at a time

Comment: The most sensible thing to do then is the [answer you have below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48995176/219661) about sending one at a time

Answer (score 1):

One way to do is to deserialize JSON into list and send one by one:

```
List<DataToBeSent> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DataToBeSent>>(json);

foreach (var item in items)
{
    SendItemOverNetwork(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item));
}


public class DataToBeSent
{
    public int CombinationCode { get; set; }
    public string Pattern { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thankyou for your response, but I don't want to send it one packet by packet, because that will be costly( we want to reduce the number of packets sent to the min)

Comment: If you want chunked valid jsons then you'll have to deserialize it and send one by one? Or could you explain your question a little bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Why re-invent the way you parse JSON using Json Libraries.

Have a look at : https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Then, something like this.

```
var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonString);
foreach(var dict in items)
{
    var jsonChunk = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code makes a lot of allocations, but does exactly what you want

```
    var input =
        "[{\"CombinationCode\":127,\"Pattern\":\"4545,.86,4520,.44,4592\"},{\"CombinationCode\":128,\"Pattern\":\"4545,.86,4520,.44,4592\"},{\"CombinationCode\":129,\"Pattern\":\"4545,.86,4520,.44,4592\"}]";

    var arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JToken>>(input);

    const int emptyArraySquareBracesCount = 2;
    const int charsBetweenElements = 1;

    var maxSize = 165;
    var buffer = new JArray();
    var bufferLength = emptyArraySquareBracesCount;
    var elementsInChunk = 0;

    foreach (var element in arr)
    {
        var part = element.ToString(Formatting.None);
        if (bufferLength + part.Length > maxSize)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(buffer.ToString(Formatting.None));
            buffer = new JArray();
            elementsInChunk = 1;
            bufferLength = emptyArraySquareBracesCount + part.Length;
            buffer.Add(element);
        }
        else
        {
            elementsInChunk++;
            bufferLength += charsBetweenElements + part.Length;
            buffer.Add(element);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(buffer.ToString(Formatting.None));
```

Answer (score 0):

My way would be:

```
var parts = JArray.Parse(json).Select(x => x.ToString(Formatting.None)).ToList();
```

Now, you can do whatever you want with each part.